# Equity Index Announcement Data

Tags: equities, data, index, data-source

Does anyone know of a data source that provides announcements of future index events (adds/drops/re-balances), specifically for equity indexes?

I know these are mostly available somewhere on each index's website ([MSCI](https://www.msci.com/index-announcements), [S&P](http://www.spindices.com/search/?ContentType=Announcement)), but I'd really like to get at the information in a more reliable way than scraping a website.

Comment: This information is not available via Bloomberg. In their FAQ there is the same question and the answer is :  "At this time, future member changes and rebalance changes are not available on Bloomberg, you can see all changes to the index membership on the effective date of the change".